# Access properties of tabBarController from view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a tabbarController that has a property I'd like to access from a view segued from controlled from the controller. I'm thinking of doing something like:

```
MyDerivedBarControllerClass* c = (MyDerivedBarControllerClass*)self.tabBarController;
```

But that seems *really* ugly. Is there a better way to do this? The more I dig into Objective C, the more I miss C++. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it